# Marionette: destroy itemview without removing its el

Tags: marionette

I have a main view that never gets destroyed and the HTML is never rerendered.
Inside this view, I add a subview.

```
   var view = new View({ el: $(".subViewClass")})
```

But when I destroy this subview, its "el-class" is removed from the DOM.
So when I try to add the view again, .subViewClass is not in the DOM, and the subview is never added to it.

Is there a way to add my subview, remove it, and add it again when the parentView is never re-rendered?
My best solution is to add the .subviewClass manually every time.

```
 var container = $(".all-views")
 container.append("<div class='subView'></div>");
 var view = new View({ el: $(".subViewClass")})
```

Comment: In general you would use [Regions](http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.region.html) for subviews. The Region's DOM element stays in place and you show / destroy the view inside of it.